# Directory 'mc/etc' does not exist

Tags: virtualization, xen, gateway

I am try to configure gateway.
I am follow step 4 of  this
https://trueconf.com/blog/knowledge-base/configure-xen-hypervisor-ubuntu-server-14-4-05.html

When I open to edit  mc/etc/sysctl.conf file I get this message:
~Directory 'mc/etc' does not exist~

Please help me, I am new in ubuntu

Comment: Must be a typo. Should be `/etc/sysctl.conf` without the `mc` part.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct please accept the answer as correct by placing the green check mark ✅ next to the answer. You can also upvote an answer. This will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There is a typo in the [instructions](https://trueconf.com/blog/knowledge-base/configure-xen-hypervisor-ubuntu-server-14-4-05.html) in

### Step 4. Configure the network gateway

#### Nexts line should read:

To configure the gateway, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. Find and uncomment the following line:

Note the file `sysctl.conf` is in the `/etc/` folder. Be particular about the leading `/` before the `etc/`.

As this is a system file, you will need administrative privileges to edit this file. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This will open the file in a text based editor `nano`. Find and uncomment the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To save and exit `nano` Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Etner</kbd>.

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont find it.

Comment: if i add it on this file, I cant save the changes